# How can I use touchpad gestures in administrator mode?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, touchpad

I have a Surface Book 2 running Windows 10 April 2018 update (1803).

I have set up three finger swipes left/right as Navigation Back/Forward. This works fine in apps like VS Code when I am running as a normal user. However, if I run VS Code as administrator, the gestures no longer work.

How can I use touchpad gestures when running an app as administrator?